# Generate different random operator on two variables in objective-c/iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I took two labels & generating random operators on them with this code:

```
NSArray  *operators = @[@"+", @"-", @"*", @"/"];
int       randomOperatorIndex = arc4random_uniform(4);
NSString *randomOperator = operators[randomOperatorIndex];
```

But the both of the label are generating same random operator. I want to generate different operators on the 2 labels. 
Such as:

If label-1 generates "+"

then label-2 should generate "/"

But now label-1 & label-2 have same operator after generating random operator.

How can i do this on iOS with Objective-C ?

Comment: You only generated one `randomOperatorIndex`. You need two! And to make sure they are not the same, use a mutable array and remove the item at the first random index (and reduce the size of the random search) before you generate the second random index. Think of it as dealing cards out of a deck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Returns an array of unique random numbers with range
-(NSMutableArray *)getRandomNumbersOfSize:(int) size from:(int) lowerLimit to:(int) higherLimit
{
    NSMutableArray *uniqueNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int r;
    while ([uniqueNumbers count] < size)
    {
        r = lowerLimit + arc4random_uniform(higherLimit - lowerLimit + 1) ;
        if (![uniqueNumbers containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]])
        {
            [uniqueNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
        }
    }
    return uniqueNumbers;
}
```

And in your method where you need the unique random labels:

```
NSArray  *operators = @[@"+", @"-", @"*", @"/"];
        NSMutableArray*       randomOperatorIndexArray = [self getRandomNumbersOfSize:2
                                                                                 from:0
                                                                                   to:([operators count]-1)];

        for(int j=0;j<[randomOperatorIndexArray count];j++)
        {
            NSString *randomOperator = [operators objectAtIndex:[[randomOperatorIndexArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue]];
            NSLog(@"%@",randomOperator);
        }
```